# Responsive design topnavigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, submenu

Im trying to get my navigationbar in my media quires to display its sublist as normal under the parent element "checkbox", though the submenu is placed on top of the rest of the list, and are not "pushing" the rest of the list down as i want. Im a beginner with html and css so i have problably made some stupid misstake, but would be very thankful for any help in the matter, i really cant figure out what i´ve done wrong..

The problem is related to the media quires max-width: 576px.

```css
nav {
  width: 17%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
}


/*210/1200*/

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 2.14%;
}


/*3/140? = 0.125% ändra padding til procent här?*/

nav ul ul {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

nav li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  display: block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: #225d66;
}


/*display block gör att länkarna fyller ut hela bredden för kolumen*/

nav a:link {
  background-color: #225d66;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #22a4b3;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  padding-top: 1px;
  display: block;
}

#lokalnav a {
  background-color: #2e7d87;
}

#lokalnav a:hover {
  background-color: #3fa9b5;
}

nav #thisPage:before {
  content: "> ";
}

nav #thisPage {
  color: yellow;
}

nav #thisSection:before {
  content: "> ";
}

nav #thisSection {
  color: yellow;
}

.submenu {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.submenu ul {
  display: none;
}

.submenu input {
  display: none;
}

.submenu input:checked~ul {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  nav {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    margin-left: 1px;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    padding: 7px 12px 7px 12px;
  }
  #lokalnav {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  nav ul li ul li {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after {
    content: " ▾";
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
  #dropdownbtn {
    padding-top: 4px;
  }
  .topnav a {
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  main {
    margin: 2px;
  }
  header {
    height: 170px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #coursenotes {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -70px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  #content {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #coursenotes a:hover {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:576px) {
  header {
    background-size: contain;
  }
  #steps figure {
    float: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="inlogpage.html">Hem</a></li>
    <li><label class="submenu"><a id="dropdownbtn">Ämnen</a><input type="checkbox">
      <ul id="lokalnav">
        <li><a href="matematik.html" id="thisPage">Matte</a></li>
        <li><a href="svenska.html">Svenska</a></li>
        <li><a href="engelska.html">Engelska</a></li>
        <li><a href="no.html">NO</a></li>
        <li><a href="bild.html">Bild</a></li>
        <li><a href="so.html">SO</a></li> 
      </ul>
     </label>
    </li>
    <li><a href="minainlämningar.html" id="thisSection">Mina Inlämningar</a></li>
    <li><a href="laxhjalp.html">Läxhjälp</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontaktformular.html">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:absolute` from below class in media query. also check updated code snippet

```
  #lokalnav {
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

```css
nav {
  width: 17%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
}


/*210/1200*/

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 2.14%;
}


/*3/140? = 0.125% ändra padding til procent här?*/

nav ul ul {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

nav li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  display: block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: #225d66;
}


/*display block gör att länkarna fyller ut hela bredden för kolumen*/

nav a:link {
  background-color: #225d66;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #22a4b3;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  padding-top: 1px;
  display: block;
}

#lokalnav a {
  background-color: #2e7d87;
}

#lokalnav a:hover {
  background-color: #3fa9b5;
}

nav #thisPage:before {
  content: "> ";
}

nav #thisPage {
  color: yellow;
}

nav #thisSection:before {
  content: "> ";
}

nav #thisSection {
  color: yellow;
}

.submenu {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.submenu ul {
  display: none;
}

.submenu input {
  display: none;
}

.submenu input:checked~ul {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  nav {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    margin-left: 1px;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    padding: 7px 12px 7px 12px;
  }
  #lokalnav {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  nav ul li ul li {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after {
    content: " ?";
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
  #dropdownbtn {
    padding-top: 4px;
  }
  .topnav a {
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  main {
    margin: 2px;
  }
  header {
    height: 170px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #coursenotes {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -70px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  #content {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #coursenotes a:hover {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:576px) {
  header {
    background-size: contain;
  }
  #steps figure {
    float: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>

    <li><a href="inlogpage.html">Hem</a></li>
    <li><label class="submenu"><a id="dropdownbtn">Ämnen</a><input type="checkbox">
 
         <ul id="lokalnav">
             <li><a href="matematik.html" id="thisPage">Matte</a></li>
             <li><a href="svenska.html">Svenska</a></li>
             <li><a href="engelska.html">Engelska</a></li>
             <li><a href="no.html">NO</a></li>
             <li><a href="bild.html">Bild</a></li>
             <li><a href="so.html">SO</a></li> 
         </ul>
         </label>
    </li>

    <li><a href="minainlämningar.html" id="thisSection">Mina Inlämningar</a></li>
    <li><a href="laxhjalp.html">Läxhjälp</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontaktformular.html">Kontakt</a></li>

  </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css style to media quires max-width: 576px

```
   #lokalnav {
      position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you to much for your time, but when i remove the absolut positioning, the first media quire for max-width: 620px; the submenu pops up obove the whole list.. you know any solution for that?

Comment: You can add this css style to max-width: 480px and remove it from max-width: 576px